# Swift: How can I make a animation happen only once and not every time I edit something

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am a beginner in swift. I am building a single view tip calculator app and i only want some animation to happen when the app loads for the first time. And not happen every time i edit something.

Here is my code:
I am hiding the container outside the view when the app loads

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated) 

    billView.center.y -= (billView.frame.height)/2

}
```

And animating it to move down

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
           super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0,
        options: [.CurveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.billView.center.y = 210  }, completion: nil)
    print(billView.center.y)

}
```

This works fine when the app loads. Unfortunately this animation keeps happening again and again anytime I interact with the app.

Like this animation happens when this function is called (which is when any information is entered on the text field or the slider is moved)

let billAmount =  NSString(string: billField.text!).doubleValue

```
    var tipPercentages = [0.15, 0.18, 0.22]

    let tipPercentage = tipPercentages[segTipControl.selectedSegmentIndex]

    let percentLabel = round(tipPercentage * 100)

    selectedbillPercentageLabel.text = "+\(percentLabel)%"

    let tipAmount = billAmount * tipPercentage

    let totalAmount = billAmount + tipAmount

    let roundedTotalAmount = round(totalAmount * 100)/100

    totalLabel.text = "$\(roundedTotalAmount)"

    let splitSelected = Double(splitValueSlider.value)

    let intsplitSelected = Int(splitSelected)

    splitLabel.text = "\(intsplitSelected)"

    let splitDollarAmount = roundedTotalAmount/splitSelected

    let roundedSplitDollarAmount = round(splitDollarAmount * 100)/100

    splitAmount.text = "$\(roundedSplitDollarAmount)"
```

Is there a way to avoid calling the method viewDidLayoutSubviews() when any data is entered in the app.

[animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jyq2.gif)

Comment: You don't want to avoid calling `viewDidLayoutSubviews` when data is entered in your app. Instead, you should invoke your animation in the right place to serve your purpose, or you can use certain control flag to make it happen only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than avoiding calling `viewDidLayourSubviews`, you could add a simple boolean flip to show your animation only once. Add a boolean property that you initialize to `false`; show animation on condition of this property being false, and flip the boolean after the animation has been shown.

```
var animationHasBeenShown = false // class property

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if !animationHasBeenShown {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0,
            options: [.CurveEaseOut], animations: {
                self.billView.center.y = 210  }, completion: nil)
        print(billView.center.y)

        animationHasBeenShown = true
    }
}
```

Alternatively, consider placing your animation in another context; does it really need to be in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (depends on the context of your app, but possibly rather in `viewDidAppear()`?)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried setting up the boolean flag, but could not avoid the animation from happening even after setting the boolean flag true. If I add the animation in [viewDidAppear()] then the animation does not happen at all.

Comment: That sounds strange. Can you see the `print(billView.center.y)` printed repeatedly? Also, make sure you declare the `animationHasBeenShown` at the class scope (outside if the function), and not inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. If it still doesn't work, make sure you dont run an identical animation elsewhere, by mistake.

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
   var  animationHasBeenShown = false

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)     
        billView.center.y = -210
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
               super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()        
  if !animationHasBeenShown {
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseOut], animations: { self.billView.center.y = 210  }, completion: nil)
 print(billView.center.y)   
 var animationHasBeenShown = true
        }

Comment: There we have it! You are creating a local variable `animationHasBeenShown` _within_ you for loop, and setting its value to `true` (not the class property `animationHasBeenShown`). Remove the `var` prior to `animationHasBeenShown` in you for loop, and the boolean flip should work as intended.

Comment: as shown above, doing exactly what you suggested: declared the var in the UIViewController and added the conditional statement in the viewDidLayoutSubviews() and set var animationHasBeenShown = true

Comment: @sudeep (note one tiny difference in your code as compared to what I showed: you use `var` prior to `animationsHasBeenShown` _within_ your for loop)

Comment: @sudeep Happy to help!